# ¿Se puede especificar la base de datos en una consulta en Java?

Tags: java, jpa

Necesito conectarme a una base de datos diferente en tiempo de ejecución y no tengo la mas mínima idea de cómo hacerlo en JPA. Tengo una base de datos que me dice a cuál debo conectarme según unos parámetros a seguir. Hago mi consulta en la primera base de datos y luego quiero conectarme a la segunda y es ahí, donde estoy parado.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Puedo colocar la base de datos a la cual deseo obtener los datos?

Ejemplo:

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    BD1.Empleados;
```

Comment: Estas usando jpa?

Comment: si. Porque? Es posible eso con JPA?

Comment: Es que la consulta que pones parece un sql clasico, pero como etiquetaste con jpa, no se si lo que requieras sea un jpql

Comment: a que te referis con base de datos? que base de datos usas?

Comment: necesito conectarme a una base de datos diferente en tiempo de ejecución y no tengo la mas mínima idea de como hacerlo en JPA. Tengo una base de datos que me dice a cual debo conectarme según unos parámetros a seguir. Hago mi consulta en la primera base de datos y luego quiero conectarme a la segunda y es ahí, donde estoy parado.

Comment: Quizás puede ser útil echar un vistazo a [Querying JPA Entities with JPQL and Native SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html). También el [§17](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql) de [Hibernate ORM 5.2.10.Final User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html).

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es no, en la consulta no puedes cambiar los datos de conexión de la base de datos, pero si hay una forma de hacer lo que quieres.

Debes cambiar los datos de configuración de JPA que están alojados en Persistence.xml. Se puede acceder a la instancia con los siguientes elementos:

```
EntityManagerFactory managerFactory = null;
Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "<url>");
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "<username>");
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "<password>");
persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "<driver>");

managerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("<current persistence unit>", persistenceMap);
manager = managerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Te dejo la URL donde se explica el funcionamiento (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583881/changing-persistence-unit-dynamically-jpa)

Comment: @SJuan76 ¿Por qué me atacas? ¿Yo qué te hice? 

Comment: Y como hago si utilizo JTA? cuando la configuración de conexión esta en el servidor web (glassfish)